# How can i add a list to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop, append

I'm struggling to figure out whats going wrong here I'm trying to append this list to a dictionary key's list but I only ever get the last one.

For example:

```
pastmoves =['n','w','s','w']
moves = [1,0,1,0]
turnpt = {'pos' : [],
          'moves' : [],
          'lastmove' : []}
pos = [1,1]
opt = [1]


while 5 not in opt:
    if len(pastmoves) > 1:
        if moves.count(1) > 1:
            if pos not in turnpt['pos']:
                turnpt['pos'].append(pos)
                print(turnpt['pos'])
    pos[1] += 1
    print(pos)
    opt[0] += 1
else:
    print(opt)
```

My stdout reads:

```
[[1, 1]]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[5]
```

I'm expecting each version of `pos` to be appended to the `turnpt['pos']` list, but that doesn't happen, why is this?

**Note:**

My if logic is nested because there are other actions I need to complete in between each one, this is just a working example.

Comment: your indentation is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a copy of the list `pos` using `pos[:]`. When you append `pos` and then change it, it will also be changed in `turnpt` because it is a reference to a list and your condition will never be `True`.

```
while 5 not in opt:
    if len(pastmoves) > 1:
        if moves.count(1) > 1:
            if pos not in turnpt['pos']:
                turnpt['pos'].append(pos[:])
                print(turnpt['pos'])
```

Comment: For the purposes of readability, I prefer to use `pos[:]` to copy a list because when I read something like `list(pos)` I expect `pos` to be something other than a list, e.g. a generator. I wonder what is more common?

Comment: Great that worked perfectly! Please could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think both of these are in wide use but I agree with you, `pos[:]` is better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in

```
if pos not in turnpt['pos']:
    turnpt['pos'].append(pos)
```

You check if pos in not in turnpt['pos'], then you append it, so after that pos not in turnpt['pos'] is never True. Example to illustrate :

```
a = [1,1]
b = [[1,1]]
c = [a]

a in b == True
a in c == True

a[0] = 2

a in b = False
a in c == True
```

If you append a copy of pos, you have the expected behavior:

```
turnpt['pos'].append(pos[:])
```

Or, if pos is never changes after that, it's a good practice to use a tuple instead

```
turnpt['pos'].append(tuple(pos))
```